# nested DIV tags and height

Tags: css

I'm trying to get some nested div tags to auto grow in height depending on the content inside them. A sample code is [given here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4HVr/). The middle  for example has some more content, but the height doesn't seem to grow. What is the trick to make it auto grow? I took out all the floating elements from inside the  parents thinking it might be the [CSS clear rule](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html). But that didn't help either. Appreciate any help.

```
 <div id="editmain">
        <div class="ticker">
         some content here
        </div>
        <div class="ticker">
         some longer content content here
        </div>
       <div class="ticker">
         some content here
        </div>
    </div>

    #editmain
        {
            position:relative;
            min-height:480px;
            background-color:#84d;
            overflow:hidden;
            padding: 20px 0px 30px 0px;  
        }

.ticker
        {    
            position:relative;
            border-bottom: solid 2px #ddd;
            margin:10px;
            background-color:white;
            overflow:hidden;             
            height:auto;
            min-height:100px;
        }
```

Comment: Remove overflow:hidden

Comment: You need to remove all your `position: absolute;` rules and rethink your layout using position static(default) or relative

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Zm6FJ/

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall - removing it makes the elements flow over it without adjusting the parent div height.

Comment: @watson - I have some elements that needs to go at certain positions - like Add/Remove/Save buttons at the top/right, bottom center etc. How do I do it without absolute positioning?

Comment: @Giles - that's interesting - I just didn't want to paste the whole code here. So something must be wrong within my element styles - http://jsfiddle.net/Y4HVr/

Comment: @TPJE ahh, I didn't see the positioning rules. Hope you get your styles worked out!

Answer (score 0):

> In the absolute positioning model, a box is removed from the normal
>   flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings) and assigned a
>   position with respect to a containing block.

[w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-abspos)

Remove the absolute positioning and find another way to format your labels and inputs using width and margin. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jim31415/25xds/2/)

```
   .tickertxtlabel
    {
        display:inline-block;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;        
        width:90px; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Thanks everyone for your tips!